# excel average if-function advanced

Tags: excel

I am trying to get the average value(s) of some specific entries. I have two columns: A-which is an index column (it goes e.g. from 1 to 1000) and B which is the values column.

I know there is an AVERAGE function and there is an AVERAGE IF function, which will probably help me but I can't seem to get it working the way I need to. 
What I need to do is to get the average value of the entries in column B that match this description for the index in column A: 3 + (3*n) in which n >= 0. In this case I need the average of the values in column B, whose entries in A are 3, 6, 9, 12, 15...

Is it possible to do this with excel or do you think it would be better to write a program to get those values?

Thanks for your tips!!

-Jordi

Comment: @simoco: Well said. What *incentive* is there for us to answer this (by the way, simple) qustion?

Comment: @user2013394: You even get +2 reputation per acceptance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an "array formula" with AVERAGE function, e.g.

`=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(A2:A100,3)=0,IF(A2:A100>0,B2:B100)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

To modify according to your comments in simoco's answer you can use this version

`=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(A2:A100-11,3)=0,IF(A2:A100-11>=0,B2:B100)))`

That will average for 11, 14, 17, 20   etc.

Comment: actually I don't add condition `>0`, because OP said `it goes e.g. from 1 to 1000`. But in genereal case you're right

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I didn't see `1 to 1000` so that may not be required - would possibly be needed if there are zeros in col A or even if there are blanks (because those would be treated as zeroes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` for this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(A1:A1000,3)=0)*B1:B1000)/MAX(1,SUMPRODUCT(1*(MOD(A1:A1000,3)=0)))
```

**Explanation:**

- `MOD(A1,3)` gives you `0` only if value in `A1` is in form `3*n`
- `MOD(A1:A1000,3)=0` gives you array of true/false values `{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,..}`
- since `False` is casts to `0` and `TRUE` casts to `1` when multipliybg by any value, `(MOD(A1:A1000,3)=0)*B1:B1000` returns you array of values in column `B` where corresponding value in column `A` is in form `3*n` (otherwise zero `0`): `{0,0,12,0,..}`
- `SUMPRODUCT((MOD(A1:A1000,3)=0)*B1:B1000)` gives you a sum of thouse values in column `B`
- `SUMPRODUCT(1*(MOD(A1:A1000,3)=0))` gives you number of values in form `3*n` in column `A`
- and the last thing: `MAX(1,SUMPRODUCT(1*(MOD(A1:A1000,3)=0)))` prevent you from `#DIV/0!` error in case when there is no values in column `A` in form `3*n`

  **UPD:**
  in general case, say for rule `11+3*n` you could use `MOD(A1:A1000-11,3)=0`

Comment: +1, notwithstanding a potential division by zero. Now, OP, upvote and accept if this is good.

Comment: I prefer to use `IFERROR()` rather than arbitrary circumventions of things like divisions by zero.

Comment: Yep, it's a good point, since OP can add some error message `=IFERROR(..,"there is no values 3*n in col A")`

Comment: thanks a lot simoco, I am trying to understand the formel. I understand the first and second part very well. this is almost what I was looking for but I think I made a mistake at my description. Your formel would work when searching for entries in A that are multiples of 3 (or of any other number replacing it)-It seemed like that's what I was looking for, because of the example I wrote on my post. But I actually need a more specific formel. for example (3*n) + 11. I think I might just know how to use your formel for this though. so thank you

Comment: @user2013394, in that case use `MOD(A1:A1000-11,3)=0`